# Sending sms via android app: Is it content dependent?

Tags: android, smsmanager

The application that I am designing requires to send an SMS to a specified destination. 
To send the SMS, I've used the SmsManager class. The sendTextMessage() method sends the SMS message with a PendingIntent that monitors the sending process and delivery process with two broadcast receivers. I've used toasts to display the status.

Now, when str (the String being sent) contains decimal characters, it's sent without any problems. However, when it contains hex characters, it doesn't send the sms, neither does it give an error.

smsManager.sendTextMessage(Destination, null, str, piSent, piDelivered);

Is the sms sent this way dependent on the content?